# enum in dictionary returning exact enum field

Tags: c#

I have created a dictionary with enums receiving enum from provider and I would like to return the enum that will be found based on the enumval so far I can just return the dictionary value but can I return the exact enum?

```cs
private static IdentityDocumentFieldType InitializeGenderTranslator(int enumValue)
{
    var translator = new Dictionary<int, IdentityDocumentFieldType>()
    {
        {2, FieldType.Document},
        {3, FieldType.Passport_Number},
        {4, IFieldType .unknown}
    };
    if (translator.ContainsKey(enumValue)==true)
    {
        return translator.Values;
    } 
    else
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Key is not found...!!"); 
    } 

     return  
}
```

Comment: `return translator[enumValue]` will give you the correct value from the dictionary. With `.Values` you're taking them all

Comment: seems to be working, thank you

Comment: Additionally, it would be better to use `if (translator.TryGetValue(enumValue, out var value)) { return value; }`

Comment: Actually you don't need to use a dictionary if `enumValue` is the int value of the enum and you want the corresponding value of type `IdentityDocumentFieldType`, you can simply do `(IdentityDocumentFieldType)enumValue`. Keep in mind that enum values are actually ints and the enumeration start from zero.

Answer (score 0):

To get value from dictionary based on key you can use [`TryGetValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=net-5.0),

> Gets the value associated with the specified key.

```
if (translator.TryGetValue(enumValue, out IdentityDocumentFieldType identityDocFieldType))
{
    return identityDocFieldType;
}
```